# Centering and floating elements in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to achieve two things: Have one element horizontally centered in a JPanel, and one element floating on the right edge of the panel. When the window gets resized, the centered element stays in the center of the panel, and the floating one sticks to the right edge.

This doesn't seem like a hard problem, but I can't make the elements play nice. It's easy enough to have the red element in the center of the white space left over from the float, but making it stay in the actual center of the window has me stumped.

[image: Simple demonstration of what I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's easy enough to have the red element in the center of the white space left over from the float, but making it stay in the actual center of the window has me stumped.

The easiest way I can see to do that is to have a "filler" area on the left side equal to the width of the component on the right side.

You could do this in a couple of different ways:

1. Add a Box.createHorizontalStrut(…)
2. Add an EmptyBorder to the panel.

So the code might be something like:

```
int width = rightComponent.getPreferredSize().width;

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout( new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS) );
panel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(0, width, 0, 0) );  
//panel.add( Box.createHorizontalStrut(width); // or use a filler component
panel.add( Box.createHorzontalGlue() );
panel.add( centerComponent );
panel.add( Box.createHorizontalGlue() );
panel.add( rightComponent );
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) can do this trick. Please have a look at this sample code and see this suits. Kindly let me know, if you have any queries:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example {

    private final int hGap = 5;
    private final int vGap = 5;

    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public Example () {
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints ();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;   
        gbc.insets = new Insets ( hGap, vGap, hGap, vGap ); 
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "Example" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel ();
        contentPane.setLayout ( new BorderLayout ( hGap, vGap ) );

        JPanel gridBagPanel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout () );
        gridBagPanel.setBorder (
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder ( "GridBagLayout" ) );
        gridBagPanel.setOpaque ( true );
        gridBagPanel.setBackground ( Color.WHITE );
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel ();
        leftPanel.setOpaque ( true );
        leftPanel.setBackground ( Color.red );
        addComp ( gridBagPanel, leftPanel, 0, 0, 1, 1
                            , GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.33, 1.0 );

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel ();
        centerPanel.setOpaque ( true );
        centerPanel.setBackground ( Color.blue );

        addComp ( gridBagPanel, centerPanel, 1, 0, 1, 1
                            , GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.33, 1.0 );

        JPanel leftLeftPanel = new JPanel ();
        leftLeftPanel.setOpaque ( true );
        leftLeftPanel.setBackground ( Color.white );

        addComp ( gridBagPanel, leftLeftPanel, 2, 0, 1, 1
                            , GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.165, 1.0 );

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel ();
        rightPanel.setOpaque ( true );
        rightPanel.setBackground ( Color.green );

        addComp ( gridBagPanel, rightPanel, 3, 0, 1, 1
                            , GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.165, 1.0 );
        contentPane.add ( gridBagPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        frame.setContentPane ( contentPane );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform ( true );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    private void addComp ( JPanel panel, JComponent comp
                                , int x, int y, int gWidth
                                    , int gHeight, int fill
                                        , double weightx, double weighty ) {
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.gridwidth = gWidth;
        gbc.gridheight = gHeight;
        gbc.fill = fill;
        gbc.weightx = weightx;
        gbc.weighty = weighty;      

        panel.add ( comp, gbc );
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater ( new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                new Example ().createAndDisplayGUI ();
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: After changing the background on the red to transparent this is very close to what I wanted. Not sure why you added the red component in the first place.

Just have to figure out a way to give a minimum width to center, so it doesn't get squeezed out when the window is made narrower.

Comment: @lwa The RED Left panel will act as a place holder for the other components and will help BLUE panel remain at the centre. Though you can try to comment out the line that sets the __insets__ ( in the constructor )  that will remove unwanted space between components